# How can I detect that my Git pull request squashed and rebased on top and what should I do locally?

Tags: git

In order to keep clean linear history upstream may decide to squash pull request and rebase it on top of the history.

In that case revision hash of resulted change would differ from revisions of my personal efforts.

How can I detect that my changes integrated into upstream with only `git` command without any external hooks (like sending email on rebase/squash to original author) or manual reviewing new patches via `git log -p`, etc?

Because rebase/squash are destructive commands after detecting inclusion of my contribution to upstream I should remove my original efforts because it is unrelated to upstream history after history rewriting. How can I do that in my local repository?

Comment: In the fully general case, you can't: someone might take your request, boil it down to a single commit, but then instead of committing that directly, *modify* it (perhaps arbitrarily) into something that no longer matches what you submitted, and commit that. Provided that they *don't* do this, however, `git diff`-ing the two "end point" commits (your final commit, and their squashed one) will do the trick, as in the answers I see below.

Comment: **@torek** So only the option is to use workflow tool and relay on its automated notifications (like GitHub/BitBacket). OK. I think that *rebasing changes on top periodically* give me hint by *huge conflict* when my (or similar) changes applied by upstream...

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `git diff` in order to verify that I didn't accidently throw away stuff during squashing.

So you have your local revision `abcdabcd` and this was merged to a remote repo yielding a new hash `cdefcdef`.

Then, you could

```
git diff abcdabcd cdefcdef
```

in order to detect differences.

When you're just interested in the files that you actually changed in `abcdabcd`, you could limit the operation on the changed files

```
git diff abcdabcd cdefcdef -- $(git diff --name-only abcdabcd~..abcdabcd)
```

Answer (score 1):

`git diff <rebase/squash> <PR'd-changes>`

All you need to do is compare the state of the repository at the commit which was rebased/squashed in to the commit which you PR'd in.